# Dynamically created html import inside a polymer element (Version 1.0)

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

Dynamically created html import inside a polymer element

Does anyone know how to dynamically add a html import into a polymer element (version 1.0)?

The code below doesn't seem to work and complains that the..
`HTML element <link> is ignored in shadow tree.`

Does anyone know any way around this or know a better way?

```
<!-- here is where the created import could go -->

<dom-module id="my-component">

<!-- here is where I'd ideally like the import to be created -->

  <template>
    <div id="container">

      <!--This is where my dynamically loaded element should be placed-->

    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({is:'my-component',
      attached: function(){

        var importElem = document.createElement('link');
        importElem.rel = 'import';
        importElem.href = '/components/my-dynamic-sub-component.html';
        this.root.appendChild(importElem);
        var app = document.createElement('my-dynamic-sub-component');
        this.$.container.appendChild(app);

      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Polymer 1.0 has the utility function `importHref(href, onLoad, onError)` on every Polymer component. To dynamically import and add your external element you could use this code:

```
this.importHref('path/to/page.html', function(e) {
  // e.target.import is the import document.
  var newElement = document.createElement('new-element');
  newElement.myProperty = 'foo';

  Polymer.dom(this.$.container).appendChild(newElement);  
}, function(e) {
  // loading error
});
```

Comment: `.importHref ` is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :)

Comment: I've found the documentation for those that want to read up about it: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can dynamically add an HTML import and get it to work inside another element but you need to use Polymer's DOM API. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api).

Something like this:

```
Polymer({is:'my-component',
  attached: function(){

    //create element and add it to this 
    var importElem = document.createElement('link');
    importElem.rel = 'import';
    importElem.href = '/components/my-dynamic-sub-component.html';
    Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(importElem);
    var app = document.createElement('component-controler');
    Polymer.dom(this.$.container).appendChild(app);
  }
});
```