# How to dynamically add elements in a template in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a dom-repeat template (Polymer 1.2.3) and want it to render elements depending on the model.

Depending on the values in `item` the template should render a button or a checkbox or something else not known in advance. This is what I tried:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items=[[myItems]]>
    <div>[[_render(item)]]</div>
</template>
```

The `_render` function returns a DOM Element here, but that does not work (as expected).

```
_render: function() {
    return document.createElement('paper-button');
}
```

What would be useful for this kind of thing if in the call of the `_render` function the template would add a reference to the DOM Element it is going to add. Then I could use it to add children on demand.

Comment: look if  it could help you  -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657159/dynamically-created-html-import-inside-a-polymer-element-version-1-0

Answer (score 0):

I tried also and there doesn't seem to be anyway to pass an element as an item to be rendered in a dom-repeat.
Depending on the complexity of your problem and what you want to render, I can only think of two solutions.

1) This is littered with dom-if elements, and seems messy

```
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'your-element',
  properties: {
    myItems: {
      type: Array,
      value: [
        { type: 'checkbox', other: 'something', },
        { type: 'button', other: 'something else', },
      ]
    },
  },
  isCheckbox: item => item.type === 'checkbox',
  isButton: item => item.type === 'button',
});
</script>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[myItems]]">
  <div>
    <template id="dom-if" if="{{isCheckbox(item)}}">
      <input type="checkbox" other="{{item.other}}" />
    </template>
    <template id="dom-if" if="{{isButton(item)}}"">
      <paper-button other="{{item.other}}" ></paper-button>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

2) This will leave an annoying custom repeat element between your outer and inner dom, and will make it harder to access the rendered elements

```
<dom-module id="custom-repeat">
  <template>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<custom-repeat array="{{anArrayOfElementProperties}}"></custom-repeat>

<script>
HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
  Polymer({
    is: 'custom-repeat',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,

        // a default value just for an example
        value: [
          {name: 'paper-fab', icon: 'add' },
          {name: 'iron-icon', icon: 'star' },
          {name: 'paper-fab', icon: 'alarm' },
          {name: 'iron-icon', icon: 'apps' },
        ],
        observer: 'itemsChanged',
      },
    },
    itemsChanged: function(items) {
      // Delete all children
      // Add new children based on items
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

Example 2 is shown [here](http://jsbin.com/cawehe/edit?html,js,console,output)

I don't really like either answer, but hopefully it can tide you over until someone instead finds a way to alter how the dom-repeat element renders to allow passing in actual nodes, or understand when being passed references to dom-nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to hook into the rendering action of the dom-repeat template using the Polymer DOM-API documented [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html). Using this approach you just need to do something like this.

```
 Polymer.dom(this.$.domrep).observeNodes(function(info) {
     var nList = info.addedNodes.filter(function(node) {
         return (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.tagName === 'DIV')
     });

    this.processNewNodes(nList);
 })
```

In the `processNewNodes` function you would append Elements to the nodes rendered by the dom-repeat template. This is not a good solution for different reasons however. e.g. It does not work together with the template used in the `iron-list`. It can happen that the node gets added but the model for the node is not yet available at the template instance. That means you can not append a child node to the list item depending on the model.

**Here is the solution that I finally used and I am quite happy with:**

I created a second dom-module for a list item which I use as node inside the `dom-repeat` or `iron-list` elements. You can pass a DOM element as a property to this list-item element.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="list-item">
    <template></template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'list-item',

    properties: {
        renderObject: {
            type: Object,
            observer: '_render'
        }
    },

    _render: function(newV) {
        if (!newV) return true;
        var root = Polymer.dom(this.root);

        // remove previously rendered nodes
        while (root.firstChild) {
            root.removeChild(root.firstChild)
        }

        root.appendChild(newV);

    }
});
</script>
```

Whenever you change the model the list-item will drop and recreate the rendered node. If you don't want to drop and recreate the item on every model change than you should be able to add a second property `itemValue` to the list-item. You could then observe changes in the `itemValue` and make adjustments to the existing DOM Element as you like.

This approach seperates the actions of the templatizer from the rendering action of the template items. So no interference is expected.